# Multiselect to the end of rows in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, multi-select

I know I can use multi-edit in the following ways:

- Select something, then hold CTRL and select something else.
- Hold ALT+SHIFT and use the arrow keys to select multiple lines.
- Hold ALT+SHIFT and use the END key to select to end of lines.
- Hold ALT and click and drag the mouse to select a block.

But what I really want is to be able to do is multiselect to the end of rows. Is there any workaround to achieve this instead of using ALT+SHIFT and repeatedly pressing PGDN key through thousand/million of rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the first row you want to select, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on the last row you want to select.

Comment: Using this method worked well! thanks, but is there a shortcut/hotkey to the end of rows?

Comment: I use the scroll bar to reach the end like --> firstly I focus on the first line that I want to start selecting from, then I scroll to bottom then I press shift + alt + click on the last row that I want to select. =)

Comment: Hey I found something, can you try ctrl + end to go to the last line of the document? In my case it works, so no need to scroll down anymore

Comment: Can also use Shift + Alt then click-drag to choose the "selection". (not *specifically* what the OP asked, but useful to other visitors trying to figure out how to get a multicursor on many rows by using standard multirow selection methods, instead of  ctrl-clicking on every row individually.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it using CTRL + Shift + End.

Answer (score 0):

1. First click on the start of the column for which data selection need to be made. Then use CTRL+SHIFT+END - That will select all data till end of File.
2. Then Leave the CTRL and END and Press the ALT key (SHIFT+ALT) and use the right arrow key to select the column data as desired.